# Use of PCA to model variance for dependent variables

Tags: variance, pca, covariance

I am working on a math problem with some friend and there is some disagreement on the meaning of what we are doing. We have 3 independent variables measured tens of thousands times and we have a model that defines 5 dependent functions that depend on the three independent variables. In other words, call X,Y,Z our independent variables, then we create M1, M2, …, M5 which are all functions of X,Y,Z  (M1 = M1(X, Y, Z), etc…).

My friend claims that we can apply a Principal Component Analysis on the 8 variables (X, Y, Z, M1, …, M5) and find three principal components that will contain all the variance observed in X, Y, Z. I agree with this statement, but I don’t understand whether this is truly useful or not. Indeed when finding the principal components we are not reducing any dimensionality and we are also using it on functions that depend on X, Y, Z, which I am not sure is legitimate. So my question is this: does the application of the principal components method make any sense in our case and what do the three principal components that we find really mean?

Comment: What is your research question/goal? Why are you applying dimensionality reduction? (if you want to explain ALL of the variance you will end up with the same number of variables as original) PCA is not supervised, so there is no guarantee that it will capture the variability of the variables that you are interested in.

Comment: It’s really not a research goal. We were trying to understand the mathematical meaning of the technique and we didn’t reach an agreement. The core disagreement is whether this method can be really applied to dependent variables and whether we have any meaningful information that would otherwise be hidden without using the principal component technique.